# Use Default Value in magento form

Tags: php, magento

in magento I've added new attributes to products but the annoying thing is when I change store view, there is no use default value check box next to new attribute field (see attached photos)

---

default magento:
[image: default magento:]

---

new added attribute field:
[image: custom attribute field]

---

How can I make it like the default magento behaviour in product edit page and in custom **FORM** in general since I'm facing the same problem in my custom form (NO use default value check box next to fields after changing store view), form picture bellow.

---

form fields: 
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set attribute Scope to Store View. So you can try to edit this attribute by updating its Scope. It seems that currently attribute scope is set to Global